# prepareForSegue:sender: is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I am following a [tutorial for building a simple iOS application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial).

I am currently on the [Displaying Information in the Detail Scene](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingDetailView/CustomizingDetailView.html) chapter.

At the end it says I should now be able to run the application. However, when I do run it and I click on a row in the master uitableview, it simply highlights blue but does not segue to the detail uitableview.

So I put an NSLog in the prepareForSegue:sender: method and it is never called.

Also, I do not remember telling Xcode (neither in the storyboard nor in any code) to segue when a row is pressed.

Did I miss a part of the tutorial or did the tutorial leave something out? Or did I just do a foolish mistake somewhere? Please help me figure out how to activate the segue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you are using to push the detail view with segue so we can offer some help.

Comment: make sure you to give the segue an identifier in the Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure these.

1) `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueName" sender:self];`

do this in below method-

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

2) set **delegate** of first tabel view.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am just curious: did you find this anywhere in the tutorial? I read this in many places but could not find the tutorial even talk about the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Did I miss it or did it do it a different way? Do you know any different ways this could be accomplished?

Comment: I asked the same thing to Kalpesh but I was wondering if you also knew: Do I need to call [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] ? Does the super class do anything important in its implementation for this method? Because when I do call it and pass it the same arguments as received, I am getting an invalid argument exception.

Comment: No you don't need to call tht method.

Answer (score 2):

1 . Add segue from master table view to detail table view , just ctrl drag and select style as per your need

[image]

2 . set segue identifier

[image]

3  in did select use performSegueWithIdentifier to navigate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tbView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Navigate" sender:self];
 }
```

Comment: I did the first two but I could not find the third step in the tutorial. But I will try to see if it works!

Comment: Do I need to call [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] ? Does the super class do anything important in its implementation for this method? Because when I do call it and pass it the same arguments as received, I am getting an invalid argument exception. When I don't call it it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to storyboard and link the cell with the target view, for linking just ctrl drag, and in the pop up menu select push, then select the cone tion and set your identifier (the one that tutorial memtions) and the method will be called at the touch up inside event and will call your method

Comment: I have already done this. This is not what invokes the method, this simple creates the segue.

Comment: If the segue is created as push, the method prepare for segue is called, its only not called when mode its modal

Comment: @BaxterLopez thats not true